# Digital marketing performance metric

Tags: web-analytics

Can anyone please give some examples which explains below metrics

Media cost spent for different channel vs Click through Rate vs Cost per thousands

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cost per mille (CPM), also called cost per thousand (CPT) is a commonly used measurement in advertising. It is the cost an advertiser pays for one thousand views or clicks of an advertisement. Radio, television, newspaper, magazine, out-of-home advertising.

CTR is the number of clicks that your ad receives divided by the number of times your ad is shown: clicks ÷ impressions = CTR. For example, if you had 5 clicks and 1000 impressions, then your CTR would be 0.5%. Each of your ads and keywords have their own CTRs that you can see listed in your account.